# Javascript to Mongo query passthru. Secure? Bad practice?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a Mongo database. I want to create a scripted HTML browser for that data - basically a table of data with a search filter, and sort by column capabilities. I want to build the native Mongo query client side, and just have the server side pretty much straight up execute those (arbitrary) queries. Is that done? Is that bad practice? I will still implement limits and authentication of course.

Comment: It's not done. It's bad practice. You can't trust what's coming from browsers as it's generally trivial for someone to modify what they send back to a website. Do not run whatever query comes from the client. A malicious or ignorant client could easily lock up your database.

Comment: @wdberkeley I know its easy to intercept and modify HTTP requests, and that its generally bad practice to "trust" what comes in to you server. Can you however give a specific example of an attack that could be used if I allowed an arbitrary mongo query document to passed to find()? Well, besides a DoS attack where user concocts long execution time query coz that is an obvious one.

Comment: Such a "denial of service" attack is reason enough, don't you think? That would be the main danger if you're receiving an object that'll you pass straight in to `find`.

Comment: The [Meteor JS framework](https://www.meteor.com/) started out like that, and still starts with that insecure configuration as a rapid-development feature.  Developers can later define permissions for what queries are allowed, or can disallow MongoDB queries from the client altogether and force the client to go through an API of method calls to be written on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The problems you could come across when doing this are:

- The user could create long running queries that abuse your database server resouces
- The user could bollocks up your datas (and more importantly, the data of other users)
- The user could access data they shouldn't have

If you can concoct ways to mitigate all these problems, then you can safely do what you want to do. I'm doing something very similar myself **except** that

A. I'm only allowing arbitrary search queries (no arbitrary updates, those are much more structured)

B. I'm wrapping queries with extra structure so that users can only see data they have access to

C. I'm keeping track of how long a query takes, and killing it if it takes too long (with the potential of doing more sophisticated user resource limiting in the system)